# Proving $y-x^2, z-xy$ generate the ideal of the twisted cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties

This question comes from Hartshorne's exercise 1.2.

He defines $Y:=\{(t,t^2,t^3)\in \mathbb{A}^3\mid t\in k\}$ and asks us, among other things, to find generators for the ideal $I(Y):=\{f\in k[x,y,z]\mid f(p)=0\,\,\,\forall p\in Y\}$.

To me it's obvious that the natural candidates are $y-x^2, z-xy$.

I've already verified that $Y=Z(J)$, where $J:=(y-x^2, z-xy)$. By the Nullstellensatz, I could only conclude that $I(Y)=\sqrt{J}$. I guess it's true that $J$ is a radical ideal (and this would solve the problem), but I don't know how to prove it.

Using the mere definition of radical didn't work for me. Is there some other way?

**Obs.:** here $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y-x^2$ instead? I'm not saying that it's wrong, I'm just asking because I want to learn.

Comment: Are $k$ and $K$ the same field? And is the field algebraically closed? Infinite? Characteristic $0$?

Comment: Also, as @stressedout points out it should be $y-x^2$ in stead of $y-x^3$; it is correct in the title but wrong in the body of your question.

Comment: @stressedout, you're absolutely right, I've just corrected it

Comment: @Servaes, in Hartshorne's exercise, it is assumed that $k$ is algebraically closed, but nothing is said about the characteristic.

Comment: Ok, just checking. If $k$ is algebraically closed then it is infinite, so both answers hold up.

Comment: @rmdmc89 $(y-x^2, z-xy)$ is not only a radical ideal, it is prime. To show this is an easy task: $K[x,y,z]/(y-x^2, z-xy)\simeq K[x,y]/(y-x^2)\simeq K[x]$.

Comment: @user26857, good one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how these candidates are natural or obvious. I would go for $x^2-y$ and $x^3-z$.

And in fact $y-x^3\notin I(Y)$ because plugging in $t=2$ yields $(2,4,8)$ which is not a zero of $y-x^3$. Whatever you have done to verify that $Y=Z(y-x^3, z-xy)$ is must be wrong because 
$$(2,8,16)\in Z(y-x^3,z-xy)\qquad\text{ but }\qquad(2,8,16)\notin Y.$$

---

In stead consider $f\in I(Y)$, so that $f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$ for all $t\in k$. If $f=\sum_{i,j,k}c_{ijk}x^iy^jz^k$ then in the quotient $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-y,x^3-z)$ we have
$$\overline{f}\equiv\sum_{i,j,k}c_{ijk}x^{i+2j+3k}\pmod{(x^2-y,x^3-z)},$$
and also $\overline{f}(t,t^2,t^3)=0$ for all $t\in k$. But then
$$\sum_{i,j,k}c_{ijk}t^{i+2j+3k}=0,$$
and if $k$ is infinite this implies $\overline{f}=0$ and so $f\in(x^2-y,x^3-z)$. This proves the inclusion 
$$I(Y)\subset(x^2-y,x^3-z),$$
and the converse inclusion is clear.

---

**Edit:** With the generators corrected from $(y-x^3,z-xy)$ to $(y-x^2,z-xy)$ the argument above works just as well; note that
$$x^3-z=-x(y-x^2)-(z-xy)
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
z-xy=x(x^2-y)-(x^3-z).$$

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to use your explicit generators. Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ vanishes on the twisted cubic. Since the $z$ coefficient of $z-xy$ is a unit, we may write 
$$
f(x,y,z)=(z-xy)g(x,y,z)+h(x,y).
$$
Similarly, the $y$ coefficient of $y-x^2$ is a unit, so we may write 
$$
f(x,y,z)=(z-xy)g(x,y,z)+(y-x^2)q(x,y)+r(x).
$$
Now $f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$ for any $t$, hence $r(t)=0$ for any $t$. If the base field is infinite this implies $r(x)$ is identically zero, so that $f$ is in the ideal as desired.

Comment: that's a very good point, @TomGrubb, thank you